# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The error in the title occurs when I try and run this code. I am a beginner and do not understand how to fix it. I have included all code for reference. All of the lines previous to the ggplot line seem to work but that last line causes the error.

```
ClassStroopData_300 <- read_csv("ClassStroopData_300.csv")
Data300 <-ClassStroopData_300
mean(Data300$responseTime)
sd(Data300$responseTime)
Data300["WorkspaceVar1"] <- grepl("_",Data300$note)
WorkspaceVar1 that contains the info whether or not the column "note" contained a "_"
Data300["WorkspaceVar2"] <- grepl("text",Data300$content)
Data300["WorkspaceVar3"] <-grepl("red_red|blue_blue|green_green|orange_orange|purple_purple",Data300$content)
Data300["WorkspaceVar4"] <- grepl("4db78970c3816d3d|a8cc6a79046e188f|c21c48d74bc99a6|dd2942c485109f3e|5eb0fbeb9b0685e2",Data300$frameId)
Data300["incongruent"] <- Data300$WorkspaceVar1*2
Data300["instructions"] <- Data300$WorkspaceVar2*1
Data300["congruent"] <- Data300$WorkspaceVar3*3
Data300["practice"] <- Data300$WorkspaceVar4*10
Data300["condition sums"] <- Data300$incongruent + Data300$instructions + Data300$congruent + Data300$practice
Data300["condition"] <- factor(Data300$`condition sums`,levels = c("1","2","3","12"),labels = c("instructions","incongruent","congruent","practice"))
CongruentTrials <- subset(Data300, condition == "congruent")
mean(CongruentTrials$responseTime)
sd(CongruentTrials$responseTime)
IncongruentTrials <- subset(Data300, condition == "incongruent")
mean(IncongruentTrials$responseTime)
sd(IncongruentTrials$responseTime)
aggregate(Data300$responseTime,list(Data300$condition),mean)
aggregate(Data300$responseTime,list(Data300$condition),sd)
MICT <- mean(IncongruentTrials$responseTime)
SDICT <- sd(IncongruentTrials$responseTime)
MCT <- mean(CongruentTrials$responseTime)
SDCT <- sd(CongruentTrials$responseTime)
cbind(c(MICT,MCT), c(SDICT,SDCT))
table = cbind(c(MICT,MCT), c(SDICT,SDCT))
colnames(table) = c("mean","standard deviation")
rownames(table) = c("Incongruent", "Congruent")
t.test(IncongruentTrials$responseTime, CongruentTrials$responseTime, paired = T, var.equal = T)
library(ggplot2)
IncongruentNoOutliers <- subset(IncongruentTrials, responseTime < 1267.0660+401.6672*3.5 & responseTime > 1267.0660-401.6672*3.5)
CongruentNoOutliers <- subset(CongruentTrials, responseTime < 1009.4660+352.9656*3.5 & responseTime > 1009.4660-352.9656*3.5)
CongruentNoOutliers$Identify = "Congruent"
IncongruentNoOutliers$Identify = "Incongruent"
AllNoOutliers = rbind(CongruentNoOutliers, IncongruentNoOutliers)
ggplot(AllNoOutliers, aes(x=responseTime, fill=as.factor(identify))) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity') + scale_fill_discrete(name="Trial Type")
```

Comment: You should be able to add much more code than that, unless it's so much that you're over the max character limit on questions (in which case, you should be narrowing the scope of your question to fit). You might try again, but with some regular text before the code.

Answer (score 0):

I made this example code to illustrate that your ggplot lines are ok:

```
responseTime <- sample(20:50, 200, TRUE)
identify <- sample(letters[1:2], 200, TRUE)

AllNoOutliers <- data.frame(responseTime, identify, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(AllNoOutliers, aes(x=responseTime, fill=as.factor(identify))) + 
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, 
                   position = 'identity', binwidth = 20) + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Trial Type")
```

Check if `class(AllNoOutliers$responseTime)` is `numeric`.

Comment: Ok well so if it is correct how come the error is occurring? Does it have to do with it being numeric?

Comment: considering the error after run ggplot(), it means a input error. If  `AllNoOutliers$responseTime` is not numeric you should do this first: `AllNoOutliers$responseTime <- as.numeric(AllNoOutliers$responseTime)`

Comment: Ok I tried that and now it says: "Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors"

Comment: what's the output of `str(AllNoOutliers)`?

Comment: > str(AllNoOutliers)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1107 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ resultId      : chr  "57dd6d64067e1e64203ffe98" "57dd6d64067e1e64203ffe98" "57dd6d64067e1e64203ffe98" "57dd6d64067e1e64203ffe98" ...
 $ participantId : chr  "57dd6c91067e1e64203ffe96" "57dd6c91067e1e64203ffe96" "57dd6c91067e1e64203ffe96" "57dd6c91067e1e64203ffe96" ...
 $ group         : chr  "none" "none" "none" "none" ...
$ timestamp     : POSIXct, format: "2016-09-17 16:20:52" ...
 $ frameId       : chr  "a9bc8be4a2aa8788" "b4d1f8fc16065f14" "9f32552d13229c0b" "9140ee1a93217faf" ...
(part 1)

Comment: $ frameName     : chr  "image" "image" "image" "image" ...
 $ note          : chr  "orange" "purple" "blue" "red" ...
 $ content       : chr  "orange_orange.png" "purple_purple.png" "blue_blue.png" "red_red.png" ...
 $ responseTime  : num  921 765 1012 725 1044 ...
 $ response      : chr  "O" "P" "B" "R" ...
 $ errors        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WorkspaceVar1 : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ WorkspaceVar2 : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ WorkspaceVar3 : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 (part 2)

Comment: $ WorkspaceVar4 : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ incongruent   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ instructions  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ congruent     : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ practice      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ condition sums: num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ condition     : Factor w/ 4 levels "instructions",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Identify      : chr  "Congruent" "Congruent" "Congruent" "Congruent" ...
(part 3)

Comment: tks, indeed you have the right data types. I am trying to figure out what is causing the error.